# Static UILabel not showing in uiview

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, uilabel

I have create a few static UILabel text in Interface Builder, but when running the application. the label is not shown in the application itself, i do not know why.

all other stuff like textfield, buttons except the label is not working 
can anybody advise me what had gone wrong ?

This is in IB

[image]

this is in App

[image]

[image]

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"

@implementation SettingsViewController

@synthesize drinkLimitText;

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    appDelegate = (DrinkTabsAndNavAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"subView:%d",[self.view.subviews count]);
}


- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {


    if ([appDelegate.drinkLimit floatValue] >= 0) 
        drinkLimitText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", [appDelegate.drinkLimit floatValue]];
    else 
        drinkLimitText.text = @"0";

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender{ 
    NSDecimalNumber *tempValue = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:drinkLimitText.text];
    if (tempValue == [NSDecimalNumber notANumber] || [tempValue doubleValue] < 0) {
        NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Make sure to enter a positive number."]; 
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Hang on..." 
                              message:msg 
                              delegate:self 
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                              otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
        [alert show]; 
        [alert release]; 
        [msg release];
    } else {
        [sender resignFirstResponder];
        [self updateDrinkLimit];
    }
    [tempValue release];
} 

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)updateDrinkLimit {

    NSDecimalNumber *newLimit = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:[drinkLimitText text]];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([newLimit floatValue] >= 0) {
        [defaults setFloat:[newLimit floatValue] forKey:kDrinkLimitKey]; 
        appDelegate.drinkLimit = newLimit;
    } else {
        [defaults setFloat:0 forKey:kDrinkLimitKey];
        appDelegate.drinkLimit = 0;
    }
    [newLimit release];
}

- (IBAction)openOntrackWebsite {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ontrack.org.au/"]];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [drinkLimitText release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Clean` your project and `build` again.

This is one of the most common problem with Xcode.

Comment: Then check that you have added labels properly in your view.

Comment: check, still not working. the only 2 whown is connected with IBOutlet, the rest is static, checked colour is not white

Comment: Upload screen shot of your interface builder, where you are adding labels.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was not setting constraints properly.  Make sure to set the width and height constraints and add any missing constraints by clicking on that triangle constraint button.

After fixing constraints, they show up.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have saved your project.
Also check whether you have done addSubView ion your code.
Clean and then run...
This will solve your issue

hope it helps....

Comment: nope i dun have any addSubView command, one funny thing is that, no matter what i added in the view, nothing is shown except text field

Answer (score 1):

Your hierarchy in interface builder should be as shown below:

```
UIView
   --- Label
   --- TextField
   --- Label
   --- UIButton
```

I suspect it is :

```
UIView
   --- Label
   --- UIButton
Label
Label
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this xib example from your MainWindow or your ViewController for the tab bar item?  Also, did you remember to change the NIB Name in the View Controller properties to the name, usually called SettingsViewController (the name of the xib file), which is what is usually generated if you used Xcode to create the class?  In your screen shot, it says "View from 'Settings'", which may not be correct.

Comment: hi macboy, the the xib example is from main window, setting is the name i rename for the class settingViewController